# Catch-all handler detect sub class exceptions in C++

Tags: c++, oop, exception, error-handling, try-catch

*Hi all, working on asking my question clearly:*

Do you know if the catch all handler (see below) in C++

```
try { /* */ } catch (...) { /* */ }
```

detect sub class errors (eg. std::bad_alloc) in case there are also parent class errors (eg. std::exception)?
(due to polymorphism/inheritance)

Comment: Not a terrible question in and of itself. But I feel there's an [X to this Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I am wondering if class polymorphism/inheritance would apply to a catch-all/final exception check as well. How so it is a XY problem?

Comment: Well. Since you can't obtain a reference to an exception object in any way that will allow you to interact with it, inside a catch all handler. It merits a "why would you care to ask?" That indicates an XY question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A catch-all clause catches *all* otherwise uncaught exceptions, no matter the type.

Comment: using std::cout << e.what(); which class will it display, the parent or the sub class exception?

Comment: @solarblue You don't have access to the caught instance in the catch all clause.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But there is [`std::current_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception)

Comment: so with std::current_exception, would the parent class exception overlap of sub class exceptions occur like in a case of specific parent class exception?
(case of specific parent class exception: )
`catch (std::exception& e) { 
     std::cout << e.what();
}`

Comment: @solarblue With `std::current_exception` you would get a "pointer" to the current exception, again no matter its type. If the thrown object is a sub-class of `std::exception` then it *is* a `std::exception` (remember that inheritance is an "is a" relationsship, a sub-class *is a* parent class).